# Binding to another control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding

Is there a way to bind to the instance of another control? Something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="Foo" Content="Foo" />
<local:CustomControl OtherControl="{Binding Foo}" />
```

I've tried setting DataContext to "this" in the constructor of MainPage but it doesn't seem to work.

CustomControl is defined something like this:

```
class CustomControl
{
    public FrameworkElement OtherControl { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you trying to do but in Silverlight 3 you can use element binding to bind to a property on a control.

```
<Button x:Name="Foo" Content="Foo" />
<local:CustomControl x:Name="control" Property="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=Foo}" />
```

In code you could always analyze the binding and get the element from that?

control.GetBindingExpression(Property).ParentBinding.Source

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible in Silverlight 2:

> Silverlight 2 doesn’t allow you to bind one element to another element. Instead, all bindings are to data
>   objects. (You could get around this using an intermediate object, but the added inconvenience means
>   it’s rarely worthwhile.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button x:Name="Foo" Content="Foo" />
<local:CustomControl x:Name="control" OtherControl="{Binding ElementName=Foo}" />
```

Comment: It's possible this didn't work with Silverlight 2.0, but for 5.0 (and maybe below) this definitely is the correct answer with regard to to binding the instance of another control.